# How to catch the invalid response from the backend and display that error as alert in UI page in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i am developing one registration page and it's connected with the backend API by using axios package it's working fine ,if i enter invalid credentials or already existing emailID it's showing me user registered successfully as alert and from the response i am getting [[invalid response 422](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKcVk.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKcVk.png)(status as 422 when i am giving existing user credentials and at that time also it's showing user registered successfully as alert [[like this it's showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vokv.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vokv.png)), i want to catch the response or status from the backend and placed inside catch block which is present inside the Register.vue component and display as a alert message(for invalid response also), please help me to fix this issue on valid response only it's should display success msg and if it's invalid means it's should display the error as alert based on response msg (if response==422 means then i want to print invalid as alert)

`Register.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
        <p>Online Book Shopping</p>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="headings">
                <h5 class="signin">Login</h5>
                <h5 class="signup">signup</h5>
            </div>
            <form ref="myForm" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit">
                <div class="fullname">
                    <p>FullName</p>
                    <input type="name" class="namebox"  required v-model="fullName" autocomplete="off" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
                </div>
                <div class="username">
                    <p>EmailID</p>
                    <input type="email" class="emailbox" required v-model="emailID" pattern="^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
                </div>
                <div class="pass">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input :type="password_type" class="password" id="passField" v-model="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" required>
                    <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword" @click="togglePassword();"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile">
                    <p>MobileNumber</p>
                    <input type="tel" class="telephone" v-model="mobile" pattern="^\d{10}$" required>
                </div>
                <button class="btn-section"  type="submit">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default {
    name: 'Register',
    data() {
        return {
            fullName: '',
            emailID: '',
            password: '',
            mobile: '',
            password_type: "password",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        togglePassword() {
            this.password_type = this.password_type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
            document.getElementById('passField').style.margin='0px 0px 0px 69px';
            document.getElementById('passField').style.width="252px";
            document.getElementById('passField').style.height="35px";
            document.getElementById('passField').style.background="$pale_white 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box";
        },
        
         handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                fullName: this.fullName,
                emailID: this.emailID,
                password: this.password,
                mobile: this.mobile
            }
            service.userRegister(userData).then(response => {
                alert("user registered successfully");
                this.$refs.myForm.reset();
                return response;                
            }).catch(error => {
                if(error.response==422){alert("internal server issue");}
                return error;
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/Register.scss";
</style>
```

`axios.js[responsible for postData]`

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL=process.env.VUE_APP_AXIOS_URL
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer'+ localStorage.getItem('token');
export default class AxiosService{
    postData(url,data){
        return axios.post(url,data).then(response =>{
            return response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            return error;
        })
    }
}
```

`User.js[responsible for hitting backend api]`

```
import AxiosService from '../service/axios';
const axios=new AxiosService()

export default{
    userRegister(data){
        return axios.postData("/register",data);
    },
}
```

Comment: why is handlesubmit `async` when you don't `await`, you don't return anything from that either

Comment: hai @JaromandaX, if  i remove async also i am getting same issue

Comment: also, in `postData` - since you handle the error, you don't reject upstream, therefore, the catch upstream never fires

Comment: how to catch the response status and displayed as alert

Comment: get rid of `catch(error=>{ return error; })` in `postData` - but still, you can't return a synchronous result from an asynchronous call, so `@submit.prevent="handlesubmit"` will never do what you want

Comment: is there another way to print as per my requirement

Comment: yes **get rid of `catch(error=>{ return error; })` in `postData`** - I'm sure I said that already - did you try?

Comment: This is the first time i am posting my query related this type

Comment: yes i removed the catch blocks

Comment: no, not the catch BLOCKS, that ONE catch block ... because you WANT the catch block where you want to alert the internal server issue (even though a 422 is NOT an internal server issue, it's an unprocessable entity issue

Comment: Yeah yeah got it, i removed that thing ,yes it's an unprocessable entity ,500 is internal server issue